# What environment do I need to deploy the virtual-maas charm?

Tags: juju, maas

I know this hasn't been released yet, but I'm trying to use it anyway. :) This README http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~virtual-maasers/charms/precise/virtual-maas/trunk/view/head:/README.md says that you can deploy this virtual-maas charm by just doing

```
juju deploy virtual-mass
```

BUT, it seems like it assumes that there is already a working juju environment. What type of environment would that be, local? How do you set things up so you can get to the point of doing the above command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virtual-maas charm does need a MAAS/Juju environment set up. Virtual MAAS just allows you to use the nodes in a MAAS server to be used as MAAS servers but with KVM instead.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I'm setting up a bare metal MAAS now so I can deploy that charm. Thanks again.

Comment: That is strange, since you can do exacly the same with just a normal MAAS installation.